# Is there a possibility to find the toeplitz matrix that has the nearest column space to a given matrix?

Tags: toeplitz-operators

As is said, if we have a known matrix $D \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times k}$ with $k<N$, is there a way that we can find a toeplitz matrix $D_T \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times k}$, which satisfies

$$ D_T=\arg\min_{D_T}\|D_T-DQ\|_F
$$
where $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{k\times k}$ is an orthogonal square matrix? Actually $D_T$ represents the toeplitz matrix which has the nearest column space to a given matrix $D$ in the sense of $F$-norm. I just want to know that can we have an algorithm to find the optimized $D_T$ without knowing $Q$?

Comment: I guess you also want to minimize over all orthogonal $Q$ otherwise $D_T$ depends on $Q$. Given $Q$ you can find $D_T$ by averaging over the diagonals. You can reformulate the problem as a minimization problem over the manifold of orthogonal matrices. With the methods in the book http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8586.html it should be possible to solve the problem.